# GIT: Move changes from one branch to other

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push

I have 2 branches A and B. 
I made some changes to A and committed them.
I then made more changes to A (by mistake).
I pushed them to B and committed them.

But now  I see changes from A (old) and B (new) being committed. How do I revert this?

Comment: Check out `git rebase` and `git reset`

Answer (score 1):

If you have pushed commits, that means the remote branch is impacted (not just your local branch)

You will need to cherry-pick the commit from B to A (assuming only one commit was done on B by mistake):

```
git switch A
git cherry-pick B
git switch B
git reset --hard B~
git push --force
```

That would override the B history, which can be problematic if several collaborators are working from the remote repo.
Another option is to revert B HEAD, to add an additional commit which cancels the content of the last one.

```
git switch B
git revert @
git push
```

No --force needed there.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout <branchname>
git reset --hard <commitid>
```

This restores everything to it's original state. If you meant something else, please elaborate.

Regards,
Zenima